# GLX missing, Unity 3d/various programs are not working!

Tags: 12.04, xorg, opengl, blender

I just recently reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and while I was installing my programs I found I couldn't open Blender. The application wouldn't start. When I typed it in to the console I got this message:

> Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
>   /build/buildd/blender-2.63+svn46744/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:197: X11 
>   glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
>
> initial window could not find the GLX extension, exit!

I'm not sure what to do. I've tried googling the issue but to no avail. Any help??!

Comment: please post your `lspci | grep VGA` output. I cannot help you for I am having the same problem with an `nVidia GeForce 8600M GT`, I am willing to see an answer soon!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)