# Blender not starting anymore, no hardware change

Tags: nvidia, graphics, opengl, blender

Using 20.04 on a Desktop PC, with a GTX 970 since 4 years. Blender was working fine until today.

Blender is now throwing:

```
Read prefs: /home/pm/.var/app/org.blender.Blender/config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
/home/sources/buildbot-worker-linux_centos7/linux_290/blender.git/intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:206: X11 glXChooseVisual() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
```

The crash file is empty.

It looks like it happened in the past: [GLX missing, Unity 3d/various programs are not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138739/glx-missing-unity-3d-various-programs-are-not-working)

The Nvidia card is visible and used:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
```

Any idea?

Comment: "*/home/sources/buildbot-worker-linux_**centos7**..."* - I'm not familiar enough with the underworkings of blender to know if the file here is an extension or config or what, but CentOS works very differently than Ubuntu.  Perhaps this is an errant config or addon?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the "Additional Drivers" application?

Maybe your graphics drivers aren't working correctly, I've found that's the best option to quickly reset the driver installation.

It should say "Using Proprietary Driver" (see image).
[Additional Drivers dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpRMk.png)

If it doesn't, select that, let it install and reboot before you do anything else.

If it does say that, you could try setting it back to nouveau, rebooting, then setting it back the the nvidia drivers and rebooting again to reset the install.